# Не работает приветственное сообщение discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, асинхронность

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channelsadg = client.get_channel(725755517066018829)  #Where ID is your welcome channel's ID
    await channelsadg.send(f'Привет, {member}! Ты попал в канал {member.guild.name}. Чтобы узнать мои команды пропипши /help')
```

Не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос выводом, содержащим ошибку

Comment: Ошибки нету. При заходе на сервер бот не отправляет сообщение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что **вы не выдали боту необходимые намерения**. Чтобы их выдать, вам нужно при инициализации бота, помимо префикса указать также намерения.

**1. Указываем необходимые намерения** *(В данном случае все)*:

`intents = discord.Intents.all()`

**2. Выдаем их боту:**

```
# Если у вас discord.Client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Если у вас commands.Bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
```

После этого `on_member_join()` заработает.

---

**Если не получилось**, то попробуйте включить два пункта на странице вашего бота. Для этого зайдите в [раздел приложений](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и выберите вашего бота. Затем, слева, на вкладке "Bot"

[image: Бот]

Включите параметры `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Дополнено:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'token'

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channelsadg = client.get_channel(725755517066018829)  #Where ID is your welcome channel's ID
    await channelsadg.send(f'Привет, {member}! Ты попал в канал {member.guild.name}. Чтобы узнать мои команды пропиши /help')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: я прописал это в коде и включил опцию в панели разработчика. Он всё ещё не может отправлять сообщения в чат.

Comment: @Disney, у бота точно есть разрешение на отправку сообщений? Если все условия соблюдены, не могли бы вы добавить полный код? Разумеется, без токена, чтобы я мог подставить своего бота. Просто, у меня все работает  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vnE0tOY я не знаю как добавлять код в ответ. Я сделал скриншот фрагмента кода.

Comment: @Disney, проблема в том, что вы сначала объявляете `client` как `discord.Client()` и выдаете намерения. А затем снова объявляете `client`, но уже как `commands.Bot()`, при этом не выдавая намерений. То есть, можно сказать, что строка `client = discord.Client(intents = intents)` у вас не используется вообще. Ее можете убрать, а в `commands.Bot()` добавить намерения:  `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX, intents = intents)`

Comment: @Disney, короче, дополнил ответ рабочим кодом

Comment: Появилась ошибка с токеном, но это легко исправить(Слетели функции в панели разработчика.). Спасибо за ответ.